# Why there is no match error when matching Maps in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am learning Elixir from offical docs.

I am bit confused about my comprehension of Elixir's pattern matching. Please have a look at below example.

```
[_] = [1,2,3]
```

gives

```
(MatchError) no match of right hand side value: [1, 2, 3]
    (stdlib 5.0.2) erl_eval.erl:498: :erl_eval.expr/6
    iex:32: (file)
```

But why doesnt below code produce such error. I feel like I am missing something.

```
 %{name: person_name} = %{name: "Fred", favorite_color: "Taupe"}
```

gives

```
%{name: "Fred", favorite_color: "Taupe"}
```

I did nothing much. I asked chatgpt.

Comment: For lists it's `[elements, you, want, to, match  |  remainder] = list`. If you don't care what to match you still have to use `[_ | _]`.

Comment: then what about tuples? ```{name} = {"Dinesh", "Pandikona"}``` gives match error.

Comment: It's tricky. Tuples have constant length.  For tuples you must match every item, if tuple on the right has 2 elements, pattern on the left also must have 2 elements. You can check something like this to learn more: https://culttt.com/2016/05/16/understanding-pattern-matching-elixir#pattern-matching-with-tuples

Comment: @dineshpandikona Tuples in Erlang/Elixir is very different from tuples in Python. For example, in Erlang/Elixir, you should not view `{1, 2}` as a container that has two integers as the elements in it. Instead, it should be considered a struct with two anonymous integer fields.

Comment: @Aetherus what is the difference btw container that has 2 integers and struct with 2 anonymous integers? please explain.

Comment: @dineshpandikona For example, in practice, `{"John Doe", :male, ~D[2000-11-22]}` can be used to specify a person with his name, gender and date of birth, but `{:male, "John Doe", ~D[2000-11-22]}` is not a person because the structure of the tuple is different. However, `["John Doe", :male, ~D[2000-11-22]]` is just a list with 3 elements with no specific meaning. Sorry that I can't say it more clearly. Maybe you have to practice more to grasp the idea.

Comment: @Aetherus I understood what you are trying to say. Thank you!!

Comment: @Aetherus tuples in elixir are the exact analogue of the fixed-length array.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin If you are talking about the memory structure then yes. But as for semantics, tuples should not be considered as arrays.

Comment: @Aetherus as _arrays in the wild_—no, but as **fixed-length** arrays—sure, it’s what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) are linked lists, which means there is no instant access to the n-th element, unlike arrays in many other languages.

Tuples in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) are lists of fixed length, with instant access to the n-th element, like fixed length arrays in many other languages.

Maps in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) are, well, maps, with instant access to the named element, as in many other languages.

---

That said, to match the above, one needs:

- *list* → specify a *structure*, as in `[one | _tail] = [1, 2, 3]`, or `[first_elem, _, _] = [1, 2, 3]` (the latter implicitly defines the exact shape of a list, which is its length)
- *tuple* → specify the length and the exact position, as in `{_, two, _} = {1, 2, 3}`
- *map* → specify the name of the element to match, aka key, as in `%{third_elem: three} = %{first_elem: 1, second_elem: 2, third_elem: 3}`

Answer (score 1):

> I am bit confused about my comprehension of Elixir's pattern matching.
> Please have a look at below example.
>
> ```
> [_] = [1,2,3]
> ```

It's helpful to know the definition of a list.  The list:

```
[1]
```

is the same as:

```
[1 | []]
```

The list:

```
[:a, "hello"]
```

is the same as:

```
[:a | ["hello" | []]]
```

In both examples, you have an element *cons'ed* with a list, which goes inside an outer list.  For the two element list:

```
element -> :a
a list ->  ["hello" | []]
```

and they go inside an outer list:

```
[   :a   |   ["hello" | []]   ]
```

In iex:

```
iex(19)> data = [   :a   |   ["hello" | []]   ]
[:a, "hello"]

iex(20)> for elmt <- data, do: IO.puts elmt
a
hello
[:ok, :ok]
```

This definition of a list is what allows you to use recursion to step through a list and stop when you get to the end of the list, for example:

```
defmodule B do

  def show([head|tail]) do  #Matches a list with at least one element
    IO.puts head            #and when there is one element e.g. [1 | []]
    show(tail)              #tail will match [], and show(tail)
  end                       #will cause the second function clause to execute.
  def show([]) do     #Matches an empty list.
    :ok
  end

end
```

In iex:

```
iex(1)> B.show([1, 2, 3])
1
2
3
:ok
```

To match a a three element list like:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

you can write:

```
[_ | [_ | [_ |[]]]] = [1, 2, 3]
```

But the nested lists get confusing when you have more than two elements in a list.  So, there is an alternate syntax you can use:

```
iex(8)> [1, 2, 3 | []] === [1, 2, 3]
true
```

Which means you can write this:

```
iex(9)> [_, _, _ | []] = [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

which is much saner.  And, there is even a shortcut for that:

```
iex(10)> [_, _, _] = [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

And, so it turns out that `[_]` will only match a one element list.

> I am learning Elixir from offical docs.

Yeah, don't do that.  Instead, read "Programming Elixir 1.6" or "Elixir in Action 2nd ed".

Comment: Your answers are quite thorough and give excellent explanations!  Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with tuples, it's crucial to provide a pattern that fits the entire tuple structure. You can use the underscore _ as a catch-all, but it needs to cover all elements within the tuple. When handling lists, you either match all elements like [a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3], or you work with the head and tail using [h|t] = [1, 2, 3]. However, with maps, you have the flexibility to match one or more keys, allowing for patterns like %{a: b} = %{a: :foo, b: :bar}.

The differences in semantics among these data structures make sense. The tuple rule ensures matching only when both tuples have the same number of elements. Lists have a similar restriction, but because accessing the head is a common operation, [h|t] syntax prevails. Maps, on the other hand, can match based on specific keys, rendering the number of elements unimportant. As long as both sides contain the same key and an optional pattern for the value, it's considered a successful match.

Comment: *When handling lists, you either match all elements like [a, b, c] = [1, 2, 3], or you work with the head and tail using [h|t] = [1, 2, 3].* -- Try: `[a, b | rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the [Pattern Matching reference](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.16.0/patterns-and-guards.html#lists):

> Opposite to lists and tuples, maps perform a subset match. This means a map pattern will match any other map that has at least all of the keys in the pattern.

Basically:

- list patterns like `[a, c, c]` or `[_]` would only match lists on the same length (resp. 3 or 1)
- list patterns with a tail `[a, b, c | tail]` or `[_ | _]` would match lists of any size greater or equal than the number of elements on the left of `|` (resp. 3 or 1)
- map patterns are partial matches only on the keys present in the pattern